# Dictionary to Excel with COM

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, com

I want to dump the results of a dictionary to an Excel file.

My Code:

```
import datetime
my_dict = {
    u'ID1': {'Date1': datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 14, 0, 0), 'Date2': datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 18, 0, 0)},
    u'ID2': {'Date1': datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 14, 0, 0), 'Date2': datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 18, 0, 0)},
    u'ID3': {'Date1': datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 14, 0, 0), 'Date2': datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 18, 0, 0)},
    u'ID4': {'Date1': datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 14, 0, 0), 'Date2': datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 18, 0, 0)}
    }

import win32com.client as win32
excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
excel.Visible = True
wb = excel.Workbooks.Add()
ws = wb.Worksheets('Sheet1')


'add in the projects'
ws.Range(ws.Cells(1,1),ws.Cells(len(my_dict),3)).Value = my_dict
```

Error:

```
TypeError: Objects of type 'dict' can not be converted to a COM VARIANT
```

My Desired Output:

3 columns of data. Column A is the IDs. Column B is the value for `Date1` associated with each ID. Column C is the value for `Date2`

Comment: is there a reason you're not using "xlutils" (http://pythonhosted.org/xlutils/)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can't write a dictionary to range object.  A range object will take a list of lists though.  In order to write the dictionary you have provided you will have to restructure it into a tuple or a list

```
import win32com.client
import datetime
xl = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
xl.Visible = True
my_dict = {
    u'ID1': {'Date1': datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 14, 0, 0), 'Date2': datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 18, 0, 0)},
    u'ID2': {'Date1': datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 14, 0, 0), 'Date2': datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 18, 0, 0)},
    u'ID3': {'Date1': datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 14, 0, 0), 'Date2': datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 18, 0, 0)},
    u'ID4': {'Date1': datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 14, 0, 0), 'Date2': datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 18, 0, 0)}
    }
wb = xl.Workbooks.Add()
ws = wb.Worksheets('Sheet1')
idKeys = my_dict.keys()
idKeys.sort()
rowCnt = 1
for idKey in idKeys:
    dateKeys = my_dict[idKey].keys()
    dateKeys.sort()
    row = [idKey]
    for dateKey in dateKeys:
        row.append(my_dict[idKey][dateKey])
    rangeObj = ws.Range(ws.Cells(rowCnt,1), ws.Cells(rowCnt, len(row)))
    rangeObj.Value = row
    print 'row:', row
    rowCnt += 1
```

Above is my quick and dirty approach to accomplish this.  Structuring your data as a list of lists will make this task much easier though.